# Dropdown populated with available AWS KMS keys as parameters in aws CFT

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

As part of parameters, is it possible to configure one parameter to accept an existing aws kms key in the same account. It would be super useful, if its possible to list them as part of dropdown.   I know the supported parameters types doesn't take in aws:kms:key . Just want to explore if there any other ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have the drop-down functionality for AWS-specific parameter types.

Unfortunately, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html), these types are limited to a few and do not include KMS keys.

Comment: is there any custom mechanism to populate it?

Comment: @Viks no, there is isn't

Comment: @Viks what is your use case?

Comment: We are creating a s3 bucket and want to opt the customer for sse. If the keys are available as list, it eases any friction during onboarding of our usecase.. Otherwise,  customer has to goto kms homepage and get the key id or arn.

we would want to provide 3 options, sse-s3, sse-kms with aws managed key and sse-kms with customer managed key. If customer choose 3rd option, and if the drop down is available which lists the customer managed keys, it eases onboarding

Comment: @Viks I'm afraid that isn't possible